Error: PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ")" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes: <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
Estoy usando el siguiente codigo para crear un bloque para un registrar los pedidos los cual he ido cargando, asignando los valores de cada producto, insertando el detalle de cada pedido como aclaración fue realizado en oracle sql developer, en un ejemplo que me mandaron despues del procedure usa ´´ para ingresar el nombre del registro pero tampoco me lo toma como valido:
CREATE PROCEDURE registrarPedido()
BEGIN
    DECLARE NumeroPedido int;
    DECLARE idproducto_1 int;
    DECLARE idproducto_2 int;
    DECLARE idproducto_3 int;
    DECLARE cantidad_1 int;
    DECLARE cantidad_2 int;
    DECLARE cantidad_3 int;
    DECLARE precioUnitario_1 numeric(6,2);
    DECLARE precioUnitario_2 numeric(6,2);
    DECLARE precioUnitario_3 numeric(6,2);
    DECLARE renglon_1 int;
    DECLARE renglon_2 int;
    DECLARE renglon_3 int;
    DECLARE Total_1 int;
    DECLARE Total_2 int;
    DECLARE Total_3 int;
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    /*Inserto Pedidos*/
    INSERT INTO pedidos(NumeroPedido, idcliente, idvendedor, Fecha, Estado) VALUES (NULL, 3, 4, CURDATE(), NULL);
    /*Obtengo el NumeroPedido de el ultimo pedido*/
    SET NumeroPedido = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    /*Asigno los valores de cada producto*/
    SET idproducto_1 = 2;
    SET cantidad_1 = 30;
    SET precioUnitario_1 = 800;
    SET renglon_1 = 3;
    SET Total_1 = 24000;
    SET idproducto_2 = 4;
    SET cantidad_2 = 55;
    SET precioUnitario_2 = 3500;
    SET renglon_2 = 2
    SET Total_2 = 192500;
    SET idproducto_3 = 6;
    SET cantidad_3 = 100;
    SET precioUnitario_3 = 2200;
    SET renglon_3 = 2;
    SET Total_3 = 220000;
    /*Inserto detalle de los pedidos*/
    INSERT INTO detallePedidos(renglon, NumeroPedido, idproducto, cantidad, PrecioUnitario, Total) 
    VALUES (renglon_1, NumeroPedido, idproducto_1, cantidad_1, PrecioUnitario_1, Total_1),
           (renglon_2, NumeroPedido, idproducto_2, cantidad_2, PrecioUnitario_2, Total_2),
           (renglon_3, NumeroPedido, idproducto_3, cantidad_3, PrecioUnitario_3, Total_3);
    /*Actualizo la cantidad*/       
    UPDATE detallePedidos
    SET cantidad = CASE
        WHEN idproducto = idproducto_1 THEN cantidad - cantidad_1
        WHEN idproducto = idproducto_2 THEN cantidad - cantidad_2
        WHEN idproducto = idproducto_3 THEN cantidad - cantidad_3
        ELSE cantidad
END;


En qué posición del script (línea, número de caracter) ocurre el error?
